# Extending Web Browser context menu in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin to eclipse and as part of my scenario, I'm generating a html file. After the file had been generated, a web browser is been opened within eclipse, hosted by an editor.
What I'd like to do is to extend this web browser context menu (when I'm right clicking on it, I'd like to add another functionality which is called "copy URL", which will copy the URL of the web page.

Could you please assist in how this can be achieved?
I must point out and say that this is not an eclipse editor, which can be extended by adding an extension.
This web page that is been opened is a web page and not an eclipse editor. it's just been hosted by it by the following:

IWebBrowser browser = support.createBrowser(IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.AS_EDITOR, null, "RDLEditor", "tooltip");

Please assist.

Thank you,
Ido

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429936/eclipse-plug-in-how-to-create-a-new-menu-for-eclipse-plugin-with-key-combinatio
It's very similar

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this in the past and the issue is the embedded browser is not part of the eclipse framework and there are no extensions or API's available on the SWT browser object to extend the context menu. The next best thing I can think of is to create your own eclipse view that embeds a SWT browser object and then create an action in the view tool bar that will get a reference to the browser object in the Action class and copy the current URL to the clip board like you are trying to do. - Duncan Krebs

Answer (score -1):

I was able to add a button to the WebBrowserView toolbar, if that is what you are looking to do.  I declared an extension of WebBrowserView and then did the following.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    super.createPartControl(parent);
    browserViewer = this.viewer;
    Composite toolbarComp = (Composite) browserViewer.getChildren()[0];
    browserToolBar = (ToolBar) toolbarComp.getChildren()[0];
    // add new ToolItems to that
```